# how to apply custom css to nb-layout

Tags: angular, nebular

Based on some condition, i have to remove "center" property from .Tried with *ngIf but it did not work.

Tried with *ngIf but it did not work. Please let me know the options.
for ex below conditions are not working :

```
<div *ngIf="!status">
    <nb-layout center>
    </nb-layout>
</div>
<div *ngIf="status">
    <nb-layout>
    </nb-layout>
</div>
```

Comment: You can refer this link https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/layout/api#nblayoutcomponent for more information.

Answer (score 0):

`center` is a boolean property on `ng-layout` so you can directly toggle it with status check no need of `ngif` here.So following should work

```
 <nb-layout [center]="!status"> </nb-layout>
```